# Button backgorund-color onclick change

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with a simple script. I am trying to make a button change its background color when you click it. I've searched here and googled it. According to what I have found, there is nothing wrong with my script. Can you help me solve this problem?

This is my css stylesheet:

```
body {
    height: 100% 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #122221 50%, #116699 50%);
}
#btn {
    background-color: white;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

and this is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<html lang="en-US">

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="learning.css">
        <script>
            function foo(){
                var x = document.getElementById("btn");
                if (x.style.background-color == "white"){
                    x.style.background-color = "green";
                }
                else {
                    x.style.background-color = "white";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button id = "btn" onclick = "foo()"> click me </buttonM>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `background-color` Should be `backgroundColor` :

```
function foo(){
  var x = document.getElementById("btn");

  if (x.style.backgroundColor == "white")
  {
    x.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }
  else {
    x.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }
}
```

**NOTE :** `style.backgroundColor` will return an empty string for the first click so better to use `getComputedStyle` so it will return the style attached to the element from the CSS.

Hope this helps.

**Snippet using `getComputedStyle` *(Works from the first click)*:**

```js
function foo(){
  var x = document.getElementById("btn");
  var bg_color = window.getComputedStyle(x,null).getPropertyValue("background-color");

  if (bg_color == "rgb(255, 255, 255)")
  {
      x.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }
  else {
      x.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
    height: 100% 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #122221 50%, #116699 50%);
}
#btn {
    background-color: white;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" onclick = "foo()"> click me </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `x.style.background-color`.
Instead you should use `x.style.backgroundColor`

```js
function foo(){
                var x = document.getElementById("btn");
                if (x.style.backgroundColor == "white"){
                    x.style.backgroundColor = "green";
                }
                else {
                    x.style.backgroundColor = "white";
                }
            }
```

```css
#btn {
    background-color: white;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
 <button id = "btn" onclick = "foo()"> click me </buttonM>
```

Answer (score 0):

syntax was wrong its `style.backgroundColor` not with `style.background-color` .and simply use with single line if condition.just like below snippet

```js
function foo() {
  var x = document.getElementById("btn");
  x.style.backgroundColor = x.style.backgroundColor == "white" ? "green" : "white";
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100% 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #122221 50%, #116699 50%);
}

#btn {
  background-color: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="btn" onclick="foo()"> click me </buttonM>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your javascript. You can use background-color but you have to quote it and put it brackets like so:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<html lang="en-US">

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="learning.css">
        <script>
            function foo(){
                var x = document.getElementById("btn");
                if (x.style['background-color'] == "white"){
                    x.style['background-color'] = "green";
                }
                else {
                    x.style['background-color'] = "white";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button id = "btn" onclick = "foo()"> click me </buttonM>
    </body>
</html>
```